# Dynamically import JavaScript module using ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

Is ES2015+, how can I dynamically import a module?

E.g. instead of...

```
import {SomeClass} from 'lib/whatever/some-class';
```

I don't know the path at runtime, so I want to I have the path stored in a variable, and I want to import a specific thing from that module:

```
function doDynamicStuff(path) {
    let importedThing = ...; //import * as importedThing from path;
    let thingIReallyWant = importedThing.someExportedVariable;

    ...
}
```

I'm not sure what syntax to use, or if it's possible to do this at all. I tried using `let importedThing = require(path);` but we're not using `RequireJS`.

Comment: @PHPglue ES6 modules are not exclusive to Node.js. They don't have in-browser semantics yet, but for-browser build systems are already using them.

Comment: Do you not know the class name or do you not know the path? Or both?

Comment: @PHPglue We're not using `node`, we're using `Aurelia`.

Comment: @FelixKling I know the path _and_ the class name (always the same class name, just from a dynamic module/path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES2015 does not support dynamic imports by design.

> In current JavaScript module systems, you have to execute the code in order to find out what the imports and exports are. That is the main reason why ECMAScript 6 breaks with those systems: by building the module system into the language, you can syntactically enforce a static module structure.
>
> ...
>
> A module’s structure being static means that you can determine imports and exports at compile time (statically) – you only have to look at the source code, you don’t have to execute it.

From [ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

To dynamically import module you have to explicitly use module loaders (like *RequireJS* or *SystemJS*)

Comment: We are using _SystemJS_, thanks!